# XAML Highlight textblock background on MouseOver

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a `TextBlock` and I want to highlight it like a `Button` when I put mouse over it. Usually, only text appears highlighted. Does anyone know how to do this? I would appreciate a example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to accomplish this depending on what your requirements are overall. Your issue will come from providing a background since TextBlock doesn't have that property available by default as a Framework Element. However here's a few ways;

1. You could use a `HyperlinkButton` template to specify your color changes etc. to the `Content` `Foreground` and a background `Border` or `Rectangle` or something in its `VisualStateManager` and just make your text as `HyperlinkButton` type. This can usually be figured out pretty quick by just looking at the default templates.
2. You could create a `TextBlock` template with a `VisualStateManager` to do the same type of thing mentioned above.
3. If it's only for a single instance or a few places you could just use a `EventTrigger` attached to the object to accomplish the same thing, like;

**namespace(s):**

xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"

```
<Border x:Name="MyBackground">
  <TextBlock x:Name="MyForeground" Text="Hover Over Me!" Margin="5">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
             <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="MyForeground"
                                      PropertyName="Foreground"
                                      Value="Orange" />
             <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="MyBackground"
                                      PropertyName="Background"
                                      Value="Blue" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
             <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="MyForeground"
                                      PropertyName="Foreground"
                                      Value="Black" />
             <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="MyBackground"
                                      PropertyName="Background"
                                      Value="Transparent" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

and that's just  a few of the possible ways to accomplish it with several others not included in this example. Hope this helps. :)